# For which values does template string literal throws?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

A simple template literal expression:

```js
`${value}`
```

… will throw `TypeError` in at least two cases:

- if `value` is a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol);

```js
try {
  `${Symbol('nope')}`
} catch (error) {
  console.error(`${error.name}: ${error.message}`)
}
```

- if `value` is an empty non-inherited object.

```js
try {
  `${Object.create(null)}`
} catch (error) {
  console.error(`${error.name}: ${error.message}`) // weird error message in this case: "No default value"
}
```

What are the other cases in which it throws an error, if any? Is there some universal rule for that (like, not having some method used internally)?

Comment: "*weird error message [...]*": What runtime environment are you using? Neither V8 (Chrome 122, Node 21.6) nor SpiderMonkey (Firefox 123) output such a message.

Comment: It's what StackOverflow's JS engine outputs, it's not me. Good question for meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: For me it shows "*TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value*". StackSnippets just run in the user's browser, so I got Chrome's message. What's yours?

Comment: Ah. Mine is Safari for macOS; same on the iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the other cases in which it throws an error, if any?

There's too many to count. Basically every object for which coercing it to a (string) primitive fails.

> Is there some universal rule for that (like, not having some method used internally)?

Not a single method but three of them. The [abstract *ToString* operation](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-tostring) which is used [in template literal evaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (and everywhere else in the spec when a value needs to be coerced to a string - in particular for string concatenation, values to be used as property keys, and arguments that are expected to be strings) does

- throw on symbols, as you noted
- call the [abstract *ToPrimitive* operation](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-toprimitive) on objects, which in turn tries to call either

  1. `o[Symbol.toPrimitive]("string")`
  2. `o.toString()`
  3. `o.valueOf()`

  if the method exists. If `toString` returns an object, `valueOf` is tried as well.
  An exception is thrown if the called methods throw, or if the properties exist but have a value that is neither `undefined`, `null`, nor a function, or if none of the methods exists, or if none of the methods returned a returned a primitive (non-object) value. If the method returned a primitive value, it is fed to *ToString* again (which throws on symbols and returns a string otherwise).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "object values"? I know that you personally use this term with a certain nuance but I can't remember what it is

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine The "non-object value" just means "primitive value" here. Or conversely, an "object value" is a "non-primitive value".

Comment: Finally got to test this (https://tsplay.dev/mqoqqw) and it's not _quite_ right: `Symbol.toPrimitive` is a bit special. If it returns a non-primitive value, JavaScript immediately bails and throws an error, without calling other methods (whether present or not). In contrast, if `Symbol.toPrimitive` isn't present, and `toString(…)` returns a non-primitive, JavaScript proceeds to call `valueOf(…)`. The playground link includes all 64 possibilities (`{ToPrimitive, ToString, ValueOf} × {MethodAbsent, ReturnComposite, ReturnPrimitive, Throw}`).

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Thanks for the correction, I've updated the answer. It's gotten only more complicated :-/ For the definitive algorithm one should always look at the current spec.